# How to find out the registration agency behind a DOI?

Tags: publications, doi, persistent-identifiers

Persistent identifiers like DOIs help in rendering (scholarly and other) metadata "open" and FAIR (findable, accessible, interoperable and reusable). FAIR data are supposed to be "frictionless" by offering "trivially discoverable" and "trivially retrievable" information.

Within the scholarly publication system, most DOIs are registered via *CrossRef*. But there are [other DOI registration agencies](https://www.doi.org/registration_agencies.html).

**My question**: Is there a single place where I can use a DOI as an *input* to get the respective registration agency as the *output*?

**Example**: Given the DOI `10.23045/jpd.2021.1.1.001`, how do I find out who the registration agency was? I can find it on, say, neither *CrossRef* nor *DataCite*.

Without knowing the registration agency, it seems that I cannot access the metadata. This seems to counter the principle of "trivially discoverable" and "frictionless" data.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can find out the RA via the DOI resolver - [https://doi.org/ra/[doi]](https://doi.org/ra/%5Bdoi%5D) so https://doi.org/ra/10.23045/jpd.2021.1.1.001 will show it's a KISTI DOI. You raise a good point. DOIs from different RAs will have different services. Some of the RAs have a combined linked data service - https://citation.crosscite.org/docs.html

However, this shows why Crossref talks a lot about open infrastructure and not just persistent identifiers. An identifier is necessary but not sufficient - there has to be metadata and services. A silo-ed RA service isn't very useful.